# How can I share my local mysql server/database to the cloud using cloudflare, so that, I can use that connection to connect to other applications?

Tags: mysql, tunnel, localhost, hosting, cloudflare

I have created a tunnel in Cloudflare and connected it to my local pc. I can access my localhost via port 3508. Now, I want to make this database accessible over the internet as my accounting desktop application in different client systems needs to be connected to the same MySQL database.

Please suggest what I am doing wrong. I am a beginner. I appreciate any help you can provide.

I have tried establishing a public hostname **db.abc.com**, connected to my localhost:3508 via TCP type in Cloudflare tunnel public hostname.

When I ping that address, I get the responses. But when I want to connect to that server, I am unsure how to connect to URl without a port as the new URL string is without a port and redirects from localhost to Cloudflare. I am not sure whether my approach is right or not. I can't place the screenshots to look at as I don't have a reputation for posting images as a beginner.

My final deliverable is to host a local MySQL server accessible via Cloudflare without port forwarding or static IP address.